# Truffle artifacts (json files) - where are they?

Tags: truffle

When truffle compiles a contract, it creates a json file instead of a pair of abi and bin files.

These json files are called artifacts, and they should reside in a known location.

It is briefly explained [here](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/compile#build-artifacts) and [here](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration#contracts_build_directory).

In the past, I used to see them after running `truffle compile` or `truffle test`.

Now, I am no longer able to see them anywhere.

Here is my `truffle-config.js` file:

```
// See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
module.exports = {
    contracts_build_directory: "./build/contracts",
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "*", // Match any network id
            gas: 4712388, // Gas limit used for deploys
            gasPrice: 100000000000, // Gas price used for deploys
        },
    },
    solc: {
        optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 5000000,
        },
    },
};
```

Does anybody know where to find these artifacts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the folder `{project root}/build/contracts/{contract name}.json`

Comment: Yes. I don't see that folder created when I do `truffle test`. Initially, I thought it wasn't there after `truffle compile`, but now I see that this folder is indeed created using the latter. Does `truffle test` just create these files "internally"? You might read between the lines and understand that my aim is to avoid compilation on every `truffle test`.

Comment: From what i now json ABIs ( the artifacts ) are just created when compiling. My guess is that in test mode, the artifacts are directly loaded in memory to be used and instanciated.

Comment: Yeah artifacts are generated and loaded in memory when running tests. Especially because there are some deployments data (address, etc) and a test is by definition ephemeral.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here are my findings:

`truffle compile` generates the artifacts under the folder specified by `contracts_build_directory` in the configuration file (or under `build/contracts` if not specified).

`truffle test` runs a compilation, but does not generate these files anywhere (or maybe generates them and then deletes them when the test is complete).

In order to prevent `truffle test` to run a compilation every time it is invoked, one can simply invoke `truffle compile` once.